# sqlite3_prepare_v2 returns 1

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, swift

For days I have a problem that is making me crazy.

I use the API swiftdata.swift on GitHub, link [Here](https://github.com/ryanfowler/SwiftData).

Well, if I launch my project on the iOS Simulator with Iphone6 it works beautifully, but if I use another iOS device the application crashes.
I found that the error is due from instruction

```
func executeQuery(sqlStr: String, withArgs: [AnyObject]? = nil) -> (result: [SDRow], error: Int?) {            
        var resultSet = [SDRow]()            
        var sql = sqlStr
        if let args = withArgs {
            let result = bind(args, toSQL: sql)
            if let err = result.error {
                return (resultSet, err)
            } else {
                sql = result.string
            }
        }            
        var pStmt: COpaquePointer = nil
        var status = sqlite3_prepare_v2(SQLiteDB.sharedInstance.sqliteDB, sql, -1, &pStmt, nil)
        if status != SQLITE_OK {
            println("SwiftData Error -> During: SQL Prepare")
            println("                -> Code: \(status) - " + SDError.errorMessageFromCode(Int(status)))
            if let errMsg = String.fromCString(sqlite3_errmsg(SQLiteDB.sharedInstance.sqliteDB)) {
                println("                -> Details: \(errMsg)")
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(pStmt)
            return (resultSet, Int(status))
        } 
.........
}
```

And this is the connection to database

```
private class SQLiteDB {

    class var sharedInstance: SQLiteDB {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = SQLiteDB()
        }
        return Singleton.instance
    }
    var sqliteDB: COpaquePointer = nil
    var dbPath = SQLiteDB.createPath()
    var inTransaction = false
    var isConnected = false
    var openWithFlags = false
    var savepointsOpen = 0
    let queue = dispatch_queue_create("SwiftData.DatabaseQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)


    // MARK: - Database Handling Functions

    //open a connection to the sqlite3 database
    func open() -> Int? {

        if inTransaction || openWithFlags || savepointsOpen > 0 {
            return nil
        }
        if sqliteDB != nil || isConnected {
            return nil
        }
        let status = sqlite3_open(dbPath.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, &sqliteDB)
        if status != SQLITE_OK {
            println("SwiftData Error -> During: Opening Database")
            println("                -> Code: \(status) - " + SDError.errorMessageFromCode(Int(status)))
            if let errMsg = String.fromCString(sqlite3_errmsg(SQLiteDB.sharedInstance.sqliteDB)) {
                println("                -> Details: \(errMsg)")
            }
            return Int(status)
        }
        isConnected = true
        return nil            
    }
.........
}
```

Why?
I imported the library libsqlite3.0.dylib, I doubt that this library is related only for iPhone6.
Can anyone help me?

I use Xcode 6.1

Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much for keeping the error message a secret.

Comment: Try using `libsqlite3.dylib` instead of `libsqlite3.0.dylib`

Comment: Sorry @CL., in the confusion I forgot to write the error message.


`SwiftData Error -> During: SQL Prepare
                -> Code: 1 - SQL error or missing database
                -> Details: no such table: PARAMETERS`

Comment: @Mrunal, i've already I have already tried to use the library `libsqlite3.dylib` but it doesn't work

Comment: Show the code that opens the database.

Comment: @CL.
`public static func executeQuery(sqlStr: String) -> (result: [SDRow], error: Int?) {
        
        var result = [SDRow] ()
        var error: Int? = nil
        let task: ()->Void = {
            if let err = SQLiteDB.sharedInstance.open() {
                error = err
                return
            }
            (result, error) = SQLiteDB.sharedInstance.executeQuery(sqlStr)
            SQLiteDB.sharedInstance.close()
        }
        putOnThread(task)
        return (result, error)
        
    }`

Comment: `private class SQLiteDB {
func open() -> Int? {
if inTransaction || openWithFlags || savepointsOpen > 0 {
return nil}
if sqliteDB != nil || isConnected {
return nil}
let status = sqlite3_open(dbPath.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, &sqliteDB)
if status != SQLITE_OK {
println("SwiftData Error -> During: Opening Database")
println("-> Code: \(status) - " + SDError.errorMessageFromCode(Int(status)))
if let errMsg = String.fromCString(sqlite3_errmsg(SQLiteDB.sharedInstance.sqliteDB)) {
println("-> Details: \(errMsg)")}
return Int(status)}
isConnected = true
return nil}`

Comment: This is unreadable. Edit the question.

Comment: @CL. `let status = sqlite3_open(dbPath.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, &sqliteDB)` this is the instruction to open database,but connection is successful! If you see the code [Here](https://github.com/ryanfowler/SwiftData/blob/master/SwiftData.swift) the SQLiteDB class is declared on line 709

Comment: To edit the question, click "edit" below it.

Comment: What does `createPath()` return?

Comment: @CL.
I've already checked, returns the path to the current folder to which I append the name of database.sqlite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sqlite3_open` will happily open a file that does not exist, and create a new, empty database.

Use [sqlite3_open_v2](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) without the SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE flag.
And use the correct path.

Comment: Thanks, excuse my inexperience